# Why the INShortcut is always invalid?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirishortcuts

I'm trying to present a [`INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inuiaddvoiceshortcutviewcontroller) to add a Siri shortcut, which takes [`INShortcut`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inshortcut) instance.

Each time when the compiler reaches out to the declaration of the view controller:

```
let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
```

It logs the following failure message:

> [NSExtension] Extension request contains input items but the extension
> point does not specify a set of allowed payload classes. The extension
> point's NSExtensionContext subclass must implement
> `+_allowedItemPayloadClasses`. This must return the set of allowed
> NSExtensionItem payload classes. In future, this request will fail
> with an error.

Here is the code for presenting the view controller:

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization { status in
        if status == .authorized {
            let customIntent = TrackOrderIntent()
            guard let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: customIntent) else {
                return
            }
            
            let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
            viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            viewController.delegate = self
            present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that *[I've created the intent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app)*, therefore I got the `TrackOrderIntent` auto-generated type.

Additionally, I tried to create a shortcut instance by using `NSUserActivity`, as:

```
 let identifier = "group.com.example.trackOrder"
 let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: identifier)
 activity.title = "Order Status"
 activity.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(identifier)
 activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
 activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
 activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Where's my order?"

 userActivity = activity
 activity.becomeCurrent()

 let shortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: activity)
```

but it gives the exact same result.

After debugging the code, I've figured out that the `shortcut` is "invalid" for some reason:

[image]

so my assumption is it's the reason behind the failure.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution to this?